# How to enable css transitions on dynamically created objects

Tags: javascript, css-transitions, transition, addeventlistener

I am dynamically creating divs that have a height of 0% which is specified in the css rule.
I then have an option/select menu that has an event listener listening for a change. When this change is applied, I want it to apply a height of 75%, which works fine.
Though what I also want it to do is to transition to this new height with a duration of 2 seconds. This transition is specified in the css rule for the element.
I cannot make this work however, it goes straight to the full 75% height, no transition.

I understand that I need to make the code 'live' in the DOM, so I have tried separating the appending and the application of height style in two different functions.

```
function makeBar() {
  container.innerHTML = '';
  let element = document.createElement('div');
  element.classList.add('bar');
  element.setAttribute('class', 'bar');
  element.style.backgroundColor = select.value; 
  container.appendChild(element);
}

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  makeBar();
})  

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  let bar = document.getElementsByClassName('bar')[0];
  bar.style.height = '75%';
})
```

It works fine however if I were to replace my second function which applies the height with an event listener that listens out for a click on a button. Please see https://jsfiddle.net/tdmitchell/3eu48zw7/30/ to see what I mean. 
Though what I actually want to happen is for the bar to smoothly transition from 0% to its new height of 75% when the dropdown menu is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the 'results' of the browser's render process are occurring at the same time - all at once. You must tell the browser to wait until the next rendering cycle before 'growing' the element.

```
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    bar.style.height = '75%';
  });
```

Will accomplish this.